# Add part of HTML code by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I use ASP.NET MVC application and has the following code:

```
<div id="divComments">
    @foreach (var comment in Model.Comments) {
        <div id="comment-@comment.ID">
            <div>
                @comment.Username<br />
                @comment.DateAdded.ToString()
            </div>
            <div>
                @comment.Comment
            </div>
            <input type="button" class="deleteComment" value="Del" id="btnDel-@comment.ID" />
            <br />
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Also, I want to add div block with id="comment-X" via jquery. I do it the following way:

```
 $('#divComments').append('<div id="comment-' + resp.Result.ID + '"><div>' + $('#Username').val() + '<br />' + resp.Result.date + '</div><div>' + comment + '</div><input type="button" class="deleteComment" value="Del" id="btnDel-' + resp.Result.ID + '" /><br /></div>');
```

Is it possible to move it to any PartialView/Html file and work with it in both places - cshtml (inside my foreach) and jquery? 
This HTML part is only an example; this part can be much more bigger.

Answer (score 1):

The first section is fine, if you want to move to a partial view you can have the partial view setup the html you want with a viewmodel passing in the information you want populated.  You would then call that controller action and then append the result to the `divComments` block.

This would allow you to add complicated pieces of html without a messy string, etc.